# Proper way to copy a const* instance of MyGreatClass

Tags: c++, constants, copy-constructor

Let me rephrase this for future idiots like myself...

Why doesn't this work? Is it because I forgot to dereference a pointer?  The answer turns out to be yes.  Ignore the rest of this sentence, it is only necessary because StackOverflow thinks I have too much code and not enough details.  I'm very happy to waffle on until the red warning box goes away...oh, there it goes...

```
struct MyGreatClass
{
};

struct MyEvenBetterClass
{
    const MyGreatClass* great;

    MyEvenBetterClass(MyGreatClass* grr)
    {
        great = grr;
    }

};


MyGreatClass instanceOfGreatClass;
MyEvenBetterClass instanceOfMyEvenBetterClass(&instanceOfGreatClass);
MyGreatClass changableGreatClass(instanceOfMyEvenBetterClass.great);
//^ ^ this line won't work because the pointer isn't dereferenced...
```

Comment: Fre you talking about copy constructor? 
You should describe what you need that code for, so there will be more relevant comments.

Comment: I...um..yes, I think I am talking about a copy constructor.  Basically I need to make a changable copy of an instance of a class that absolutely must not be changed.

Comment: Also maybe it will be more safety to avoid using a such big count of pointers in C++? And use references instead? Also another approach is to use MyGreatClass::Clone() instead of copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the implicitly declared copy constructor of MyGreatClass to make the copy:

```
MyGreatClass changableGreatClass(*instanceOfMyEvenBetterClass.great);
                              // ^ dereference the pointer
```